# Sens figuré rare de « roter »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

On peut entendre au point [15m50s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkKF6sx4IW4&t=950s) du documentaire historique « *L'encombrant monsieur Pétain* », les commentaires suivants dus à un ancien ministre, Robert Badinter.

> C'est un régime  qui vivait dans l'adoration d'un vieillard *rotant*, chevrotant, partout des photos de lui dans les actualités, le maréchal, le maréchal, le maréchal…

Il est très clair qu'il s'agit du mot « rotant », participe présent du verbe « roter » ; l'entrée « roter » dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/roter) ne fournit aucune indication d'un sens figuré qui serait une explication plausible de l'utilisation de ce mot dans le contexte donné, puisqu'il semble évident que c'est essentiellement du comportement de Pétain en public dont il s'agit.

> B. − Empl. trans., au fig. **Proférer avec violence.**
> ♦ L'ivrogne rentrait à tâtons, bousculant tout, rotant le blasphème et l'ordure (Bloy,Femme pauvre, 1897, p. 41).

Ni le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/roter) ni le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/roter/69939) ne fournissent de sens figuré, ce qui tendrait à laisser supposer que le sens figuré porté au TLFi ne constituerait pas une acception très courante. D'après le [style d'élocution de Pétain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNMswtqJ0gg) rien ne laisse supposer qu'il aurait parlé d'une façon particulière en ce qui concerne la prononciation des mots.

Comment doit-on donc comprendre ce mot dans l'énonciation ci-dessus ? Quelqu'un serait-il conscient d'un sens figuré peu connu qui expliquerait bien les propos de Badinter et confirmerait  sa description comme étant judicieuse ?

Comment: Couldn't the addition of "chevrotant" right after "rotant" indicate that Badinter was second guessing his use of "rotant" or at least expanding it to include "(meme) chevrotant" regardless of what he meant by "rotant"?

Comment: @PapaPoule It is difficult to ignore this apparently innocuous, but powerful "rhyming"; I nevertheless chose not to consider delving into various perspectives that derive from it, in particular that which you point to (and that didn't occur to me); on second thought, as prompted by your comments, I come to believe that there might be more lying behind this "repetition" than meet the eye.

Answer (score 3):

Toutes les acceptions du mot sont à mon avis plausibles. Badinter dresse le portrait d'un vieillard en fin de vie et qu'il veut montrer comme étant dépassé par les événements. La voix de Pétain était à cette époque effectivement chevrotante et les tremblements d'une voix qui chevrote peuvent faire entendre des bruits irréguliers de toute nature. Le portrait se veut sans complaisance et le choix du mot péjoratif pour parler de ces bruits est plausible. Ce n'est qu'une interprétation de base.

Personnellement je pense plutôt au sens figuré du mot. Là aussi il y a le choix entre *éructer*<sup>1</sup> et *roter*. J'ai déjà entendu *roter* employé dans ce sens, et le fait que ce sens ne figure pas dans le Larousse ne prouve en rien qu'il soit tombé en désuétude totale, cet emploi est ancien, et courant en moyen  français<sup>2</sup>.  Le Larousse en ligne, donne ce sens à [éructer](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9ructer/30862) et les deux mots sont quasiment toujours synonymes. Si *éructer* est déjà péjoratif dans ce sens, *roter* l'est encore plus. Badinter aurait très bien pu parler d'un vieillard *éructant*, mais on comprend facilement son choix du mot le plus péjoratif pour décrire quelqu'un qui, de son point de vue, profère des inepties.

Une troisième interprétation est encore possible. Le DMF nous donne aussi le sens, celui-ci me semble-t-il effectivement perdu de nos jours, de [*mourir*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/roter?idf=dmfXgXrmXrjfh;str=0). Badinter était un homme instruit et excellent orateur. Il est trop tard pour le lui demander mais peut-être avait-il aussi ce sens en tête en faisant le portrait de ce vieillard cacochyme.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> : Au fig., emploi trans., péj., fam. Exprimer bruyamment (une idée violente, un sentiment grossier). ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9ructer))

<sup>2</sup> [Voir le Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/roter)</sup>

Comment: Cette caractérisation de Pétain en tant que vieillard, qui est un terme extrême dans ce contexte historique particulier, ne répond pas à la réalité. C'était un homme qui jusqu'à la fin de sa carrière politique,  et ultérieurement, a été reconnu comme lucide, un homme qui a refusé de plaider la sénilité à son procès, un homme qu'on a reconnu comme  totalement responsable lors même de ce procès : il n'a pas été pris aux assises pour un viellard avachi mais pour quelqu'un en parfaite possession de ses moyens, loin d'être un mourant ; ces faits sont  corroborés par ses derniers discours.

Comment: @LPH Tout dépend de quel point de vue on se place. Toute explication de texte se fait en tenant compte du locuteur. Les mot de « vieillard rotant, chevrotant » sont ceux de Badinter. On explique en se mettant dans la tête du locuteur, pas difficile en l'occurrence vu que  Badinter n'a jamais caché ses opinions, partagées par beaucoup d'ailleurs.  « vieillard  chevrotant » suffit à donner le ton, mais « rotant » cadre avec les deux mots, quel que soit le sens que tu veuilles lui donner. On rote des injures, on rote des inepties, on rote toutes sortes de choses.

Comment: Tu as le droit de ne pas aimer mon explication, par contre ce n'est pas la place ici de parler de la « lucidité » de Pétain,  mais puisque tu abordes le sujet que je me serais bien gardé d'aborder,   je te rappelle  l'article paru il y a quelques années,  écrit par un professeur de gériatrie qui ayant  étudié  les écrits et le comportement de Pétain dans le cadre de ses recherches  a émis l'hypothèse qu'il ait été atteint d'une maladie neurovégétative (il me semble qu'il parlait de la maladie d’Alzheimer).  Et ces troubles seraient apparus bien avant 1939.

Comment: Ce n'est pas exactement que je ne l'aime pas, elle cherche à discerner un sens figuré qui serait plausible, et qui serait à mon avis la seule possibilité de comprendre ces mots ; je ne sais pas dans quelles limites on peut considérer qu'un usage ressort de l'image personnelle, mais si c'est le cas d'un usage figuré personnel je ne trouve rien dans l'histoire qui évoque cette idée apparemment exagérée : dans ses discours, indépendamment du contenu politique, il s'exprime aussi normalement qu'un autre politicien, pas comme un   un vieillard, et cela a été reconnu par certains historiens. (1/2)

Comment: On aurait pu dire du Pape Jean Paul II, par exemple, que pendant les derniers mois de son pontificat, il n'était plus qu'un vieillard qui n'avait pas tous ses moyens, mais de toute façon de telles descriptions que celle de Badinter n'avaient pas la moindre légitimité, comme c'est d'ailleurs  le cas pour tous les vieillards dans la même  situation. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH Je ne comprends  « elle cherche à discerner un sens figuré qui serait plausible » Quel usage « personnel » ? il  s'agit du sens que tu as trouvé toi-même dans le TLF, employé ici sans COD, c'est tout. Je n'y vois moi rien d'autre. Mais c'est ouvert à toute interprétation qu'on veut et j'ai donné les trois possibles. Je ne comprends  « elle cherche à discerner un sens figuré qui serait plausible » Il n'y a pas d'usage « personnel » il  s'agit du sens que tu as trouvé toi-même dans le TLF, employé ici sans COD, c'est tout. Je n'y vois moi rien d'autre. Mais c'est ouvert à toute interprétati

Comment: qu'on veut et j'ai donné les trois possibles. Si tu trouves les mots de « vieillard rotant, chevrotant » exagérés ou sans « légitimité » il ne faut pas poser la question car toute réponse ne peut qu'exprimer une opinion, un mot ne peut être expliquer que dans son contexte. On peut être un vieillard et être excellent politicien, l'âge ne fait rien à l'affaire. Tu as le droit de penser (et tu n'es pas le seul) que  Pétain était lucide jusqu'à la fin de sa vie.

Comment: Tu oublies que tous les historiens ne sont pas de cet avis : « [Agé de 84 ans en 1940, la santé mentale déclinante du maréchal Pétain lors de la signature de l'armistice avec l'Allemagne nazie était connue des historiens](https://france3-regions.francetvinfo.fr/hauts-de-france/somme/amiens/petain-souffrait-il-maladie-alzheimer-theorie-medecin-amiens-1632980.html) ». La sénilité de Pétain à la fin de sa vie [était bien connue](https://www.lamontagne.fr/tulle-19000/actualites/petain-ou-la-chronique-dun-naufrage-les-memoires-de-son-medecin-originaire-de-tulle-publies_12571915/).

Comment: Ma plume a fourché, je parle bien sûr à plusieurs reprises de maladie **neurodégénérative** ! À rectifier donc. La flemme de tout réécrire....  Et lire un mot ne peut être expliqu**é**.